# Sort option values ASC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to sort my select option values correctely. My select element is returning the text values as followed :

```
** Please choose
2-3 pers.
16-18 pers.
20-24 pers
3-4 pers.
4-6 pers.
5-7 pers
6-8 pers.
8-10 pers.
10-12 pers.
12-14 pers.
14-16 pers.
16-18 pers.
```

I understand that javascript is sorting as followed :

```
""
1
10
11
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But I would like to have it sorted from "" to 11 ("",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11). Would appreciate some expertise here. Thanks.

HTML :

```
<select class="form-control" id="dessertservingID" data-value="10" name="dessertservingID" required="">
<option value="">** Please choose</option>
<option value="7">10-12 pers.</option>
<option value="8">12-14 pers.</option>
<option value="9">14-16 pers.</option>
<option selected="" value="10">16-18 pers.</option>
<option value="1">2-3 pers.</option>
<option value="11">20-24 pers.</option>
<option value="2">3-4 pers.</option>
<option value="3">4-6 pers.</option>
<option value="4">5-7 pers.</option>
<option value="5">6-8 pers.</option>
<option value="6">8-10 pers.</option>
</select>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
    var options = $('#dessertservingID option');
    options.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.value > b.value) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (a.value < b.value) {
    return -1;
    }
    else {
    return 0;
    }
})

$("#dessertservingID").empty().append(options);

// Vive la France!

$('#dessertservingID option[value=""]').insertAfter($('#dessertservingID option:first'));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you're comparing the `value` properties as strings. Convert them to integers using `parseInt()` first.

Also note that you can simplify your `sort()` logic by simply subtracting one value from the other:

```js
$(function() {
  var $options = $('#dessertservingID option');
  $options.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.value, 10) - parseInt(b.value, 10);
  })

  $("#dessertservingID").empty().append($options);

  $('#dessertservingID option[value=""]').insertAfter($('#dessertservingID option:first'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="dessertservingID" data-value="10" name="dessertservingID" required="">
  <option value="">** Please choose</option>
  <option value="7">10-12 pers.</option>
  <option value="8">12-14 pers.</option>
  <option value="9">14-16 pers.</option>
  <option selected="" value="10">16-18 pers.</option>
  <option value="1">2-3 pers.</option>
  <option value="11">20-24 pers.</option>
  <option value="2">3-4 pers.</option>
  <option value="3">4-6 pers.</option>
  <option value="4">5-7 pers.</option>
  <option value="5">6-8 pers.</option>
  <option value="6">8-10 pers.</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get the numeric value of the string. It will try to get any numeric values *from the beginning* of the string until it encounters a non-numeric value. In your case, that is what you want - you will get `20` out of `"20-24"`:

```js
$(function() {
  var options = $('#dessertservingID option');
  options.sort(function(a, b) {
    //parse the values
    var valueA = parseInt(a.value);
    var valueB = parseInt(b.value);
    if (valueA > valueB) {
      return 1;
    } else if (valueA < valueB) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  })

  $("#dessertservingID").empty().append(options);

  $('#dessertservingID option[value=""]').insertAfter($('#dessertservingID option:first'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="dessertservingID" data-value="10" name="dessertservingID" required="">
  <option value="">** Please choose</option>
  <option value="7">10-12 pers.</option>
  <option value="8">12-14 pers.</option>
  <option value="9">14-16 pers.</option>
  <option selected="" value="10">16-18 pers.</option>
  <option value="1">2-3 pers.</option>
  <option value="11">20-24 pers.</option>
  <option value="2">3-4 pers.</option>
  <option value="3">4-6 pers.</option>
  <option value="4">5-7 pers.</option>
  <option value="5">6-8 pers.</option>
  <option value="6">8-10 pers.</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing option.value into an integer using parseInt before comparing the values:

```
$(function() {
    var options = $('#dessertservingID option');
    options.sort(function(a, b) {

    let aValue = parseInt(a.value);
    let bValue = parseInt(b.value);

    aValue = isNaN(aValue) ? -1 : aValue;
    bValue = isNaN(bValue) ? -1 : bValue;

    return aValue - bValue;
})
```

Using parseInt forces proper numeric comparison instead of comparing the keycode values of the strings. The isNaN check is for the blank value, and setting the value to -1 if the parsed integer is NaN, ensures that it is the first returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
options.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value-b.value;
})
```

Instead, to sort your numbers, there is no need for if statements. This will implicitly cast your values to numbers and calculate the difference.

See working example below:

```js
$(function() {
  var options = $('#dessertservingID option');
  options.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value-b.value;
  })

  $("#dessertservingID").empty().append(options);

  $('#dessertservingID option[value=""]').insertAfter($('#dessertservingID option:first'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="dessertservingID" data-value="10" name="dessertservingID" required="">
  <option value="">** Please choose</option>
  <option value="7">10-12 pers.</option>
  <option value="8">12-14 pers.</option>
  <option value="9">14-16 pers.</option>
  <option selected="" value="10">16-18 pers.</option>
  <option value="1">2-3 pers.</option>
  <option value="11">20-24 pers.</option>
  <option value="2">3-4 pers.</option>
  <option value="3">4-6 pers.</option>
  <option value="4">5-7 pers.</option>
  <option value="5">6-8 pers.</option>
  <option value="6">8-10 pers.</option>
</select>
```